# Using Gson to convert a String[Youtube v3 api response] starting with 'null' into JsonObject in Java

Tags: java, json, api, youtube, gson

Good afternoon dear Stack-overflowees!

I've got the following youtube response for a query for videos from a HTTPRequest:

```
null{ "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse", "etag": "\"5g01s4-    S2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/MnX_l4A0-CoCz7AqTuwYbZZ8Eos\"", "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA","regionCode": "NL", "pageInfo": {  "totalResults": 1000000,  "resultsPerPage": 10 }, "items": [  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/3x0aJRM9h33YMFvqksUj6alhFqU\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "_nws2egRR1w"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2015-06-26T19:00:00.000Z",    "channelId": "UCY30JRSgfhYXA6i6xX1erWg",    "title": "GODS IN REAL LIFE",    "description": "Thank you to Smite for sponsoring this video! SMITE is an online battleground where the Gods of Old wage war in the name of conquest, glory, and most of all, ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_nws2egRR1w/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_nws2egRR1w/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_nws2egRR1w/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "Smosh",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/K_ZgSkXsMidzJqa-m1IoLJU6UBE\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "UiPZFPYhmzs"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2014-03-22T18:02:28.000Z",    "channelId": "UCo_IB5145EVNcf8hw1Kku7w",    "title": "Game Theory: Are SMITE's Goddesses TOO SEXY?",    "description": "Become a Theorist! â–» http://.com/mrd2ntg SMITE is a MOBA with fast-paced action, terrific game modes, and well-endowed goddesses. In fact, the ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UiPZFPYhmzs/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UiPZFPYhmzs/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UiPZFPYhmzs/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "The Game Theorists",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/wITeN0CQk1zT1C9k6Pm4BpvN3Jk\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "5mVYnfJS73U"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2016-01-05T14:00:01.000Z",    "channelId": "UCLB_2GSFGa4Unb5fjq49SOw",    "title": "SMITE Cinematic Trailer - 'To Hell & Back'",    "description": "Welcome to SMITE, the online Battleground of the Gods. Play free at www.SmiteGame.com and seize victory in intense battles of strategic action, each fueled by ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5mVYnfJS73U/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5mVYnfJS73U/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5mVYnfJS73U/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "SMITE by Hi-Rez Studios",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/e5NJ3_X-R_m5PEqxSbN26lIAsJo\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "Chu1XqxoQio"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2015-07-16T17:03:55.000Z",    "channelId": "UCWeg2Pkate69NFdBeuRFTAw",    "title": "LE DIEU DE LA LOOSE ! (Smite)",    "description": "On a pas l'habitude de jouer Ã  ce genre de jeux, mais Ã§a change un peu ! Par contre on se fait dÃ©foncer Ã§a Ã§a changera jamais :') Les rÃ¨gles : 10 Dieux ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Chu1XqxoQio/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Chu1XqxoQio/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Chu1XqxoQio/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "SQUEEZIE",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/j2Z6NrL6kZ7BqCqLC9T-iDIwVMo\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "vAnVb_oBF7I"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2014-06-07T19:00:02.000Z",    "channelId": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",    "title": "3 HEROES, 3 QUESTIONS! - Smite: Tournament",    "description": "Will they get good? Will Cry find love? Will they get a kill? Find out here!: http://ly/1p1xH05 http://youtu.be/lrXsGQO6Hrs I edited the first part of this video, Cry ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vAnVb_oBF7I/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vAnVb_oBF7I/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vAnVb_oBF7I/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "PewDiePie",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/9_S9Q9n9KHeFGuPeBIlxzFHp8hc\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "CSFibeWqXaM"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2015-08-02T16:01:42.000Z",    "channelId": "UCLB_2GSFGa4Unb5fjq49SOw",    "title": "SCL Spring Split Week 1 Day 4",    "description": "",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CSFibeWqXaM/default_live.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CSFibeWqXaM/mqdefault_live.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CSFibeWqXaM/hqdefault_live.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "SMITE by Hi-Rez Studios",    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/_HsRcEb5SgSrO7KDYGVcWnM-IyE\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "4I7kDcRdM2Q"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2012-06-02T07:31:19.000Z",    "channelId": "UCTy_oLoGaQnV7LeiOkxx3qw",    "title": "SMITE Gameplay (Part 1) - First Look HD",    "description": "http://mmohuts.com/preview/smite for SMITE reviews, videos, screenshots and more. SMITE is a third person MOBA published by Hi-Rez Studios . MMOHuts has ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4I7kDcRdM2Q/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4I7kDcRdM2Q/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4I7kDcRdM2Q/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "MMOHuts",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/NFvQY8IZQap1sIr8ovsni7HsLAI\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "OwAC1VD1608"   },   "snippet": {    "publishedAt": "2015-04-12T23:00:00.000Z",    "channelId": "UCda7Fl9Q4wmqDqASRDqrVbA",    "title": "COCIELO TESTE, O CRACUDO - DetonaTHOR Smite [2/2]",    "description": "BAIXE E JOGUE SMITE DE GRAÃ‡A: http://lup.vc/JogueSmite_Muca PARTE 1 DO EVENTO: https://youtu.be/DHtOrB63DD0 Instagram: ...",    "thumbnails": {     "default": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OwAC1VD1608/default.jpg",      "width": 120,      "height": 90     },     "medium": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OwAC1VD1608/mqdefault.jpg",      "width": 320,      "height": 180     },     "high": {      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OwAC1VD1608/hqdefault.jpg",      "width": 480,      "height": 360     }    },    "channelTitle": "Muca MuriÃ§oca",    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"   }  },  {   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/_QFud2t95zRYczOqcudKnUHL4r8\"",   "id": {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "videoId": "6q0uAevwQ2Q"
```

Only the first part is actually relevent, seeing as how the response starts off with a 'null'.

Now i've tried using the following code to parse the json using GSON.(result being the aforementioned JSON as a String.

```
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(result);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("items");
```

However, Gson cannot work around the 'null' at the front of the json string. It converts the entire object in the first line not into a JsonElement but JsonNull.

Is there any way to try and get the array called 'items' from the string directly?

I've tried replacing the null with another word, i've tried several other things such as GsonBuilder.serializeNulls() and several other stackoverflow entried, yet I cannot work around this.

Any help/tips would be very much appreciated.

--edit--
 following java code is used to call the api:

```
     private String baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&order=viewCount&q=";

    String output;
    String result = "";
    URL url = new URL(this.baseUrl + q + "&type=video&key=" + key);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result += output;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON you are trying to parse, so instead of pushing the parser to accept the string, I would try figure out why there's a `null` in the first place. How did you get the result?

Comment: I did cut out a large part from the end due to the first part being relevant. It is a response from the youtube API, so i'm guessing that'd be a valid JSON?

Comment: No valid JSON starts with `null{`. The server is very unlikely to respond invalid JSON. But that `null` can come from the code communicating with the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your'e result is initiated with null so "result+=output" will be null"output" cause a NullPointer results in "null" in "+" string concatenation. Think thats your problem. Either init it with empty String or check in your while loop for null.